# Input css style

Tags: html, css

Hi all i need create input in html css as the picture below.

I would be grateful if you send an example. I've tried some options with before and after but they didn't work.

[image: Example]

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your effort, we'll help you.

Comment: As you can see, it took less than 30 seconds to find a dupe

Answer (score -1):

I really recommend that you use Bootstrap.
It's the most popular and easy css framework.

See below the how to install and some examples:

Install -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Some Forms Styles -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/

Some Inputs Styles -> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Comment: Why would this answer the question at all? OP wants half height input borders. [Don't just paste links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259)